# macOS Catalina causing "find: .: Operation not permitted" errors

Tags: terminal, finder, automator, catalina

I have an automation workflow that I use as a Quick Action.  It takes a Finder item and calls a shell script with it.  Part of the shell script runs a find command on the directory of the Finder item.  Prior to Catalina, this worked.  Now I get

```
find: <path to the directory>: Operation not permitted
```

This only happens when I'm running it as the Service Quick Action.  If I call the script in Terminal, it works fine, as does the find command in Terminal.

```
# Directory to delete files from
REAL_FILE=$(/usr/local/bin/realpath "$1")
DIR=$(dirname "$REAL_FILE")

find "$DIR" -type f -depth 1 -print0 | while read -d $'\0' FILE
do
    if [[ "$FILE" < "$REAL_FILE" ]] ; then
        mv "$FILE" ~/.Trash/
    fi
done
```

Comment: What shell have you selected in the “Run Shell Script” block? Try giving that shell Full Disk Access *(System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant the Finder full disk access:

1. Open Security & Privacy preferences
2. Go to the Full Disk Access option.
3. Click the plus button.
4. Locate the Finder in `/System/Library/CoreServices/` (or simply type 'Finder' into Search).

Compare [Grant “Full Disk Access” to Workflows run via the Services menu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342898/grant-full-disk-access-to-workflows-run-via-the-services-menu).

Answer (score 3):

I had a somewhat related issue. I created a periodic script that was running under `/etc/daily.local`. This was on macOS Catalina. It had the following line:

```sh
find "/Users/brianc/Downloads" -Btime +3d -name 'GBH4SN2*.rdp' -type f -print
```

And when the script ran, I would see the following:

```sh
find: /Users/brianc/Downloads: Operation not permitted
```

So, I granted Full Disk Access (*System Preferences* > *Security & Privacy* > *Privacy* > *Full Disk Access*) to `find`. No difference. Granted FDA to `bash`. No difference. Granted FDA to `sh`. No difference. Finally, by going through all the different scripts, I found that periodic scripts are run under `/usr/libexec/periodic-wrapper` which is executed from `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-daily.plist`. So, I granted FDA to `periodic-wrapper`. Problem solved.

Comment: So for `/etc/daily.local` it's a matter of giving `/usr/libexec/periodic-wrapper` FDA. For LaunchAgents, it's giving FDA to `bash` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60500021/1913230)). But the OP asked about Quick Actions...

Comment: It didn’t work for me. I launch the script with cron and granting FDA to `/usr/sbin/cron` seems to have done the trick.